# datagridview font color + mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

In MySql is 8 columns(col1,col2,...,col8) and 100 rows. 
In DataGridView is 3 columns(1,2,3). 
Column(8) "priorita" has only this strings:

```
 string a1 = "black";
 string a2 = "blue";
 string a3 = "red";
```

now I need load all strings from "priorita" columns and change text color in DGV

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {

        using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection("Server=@@@;Database=OitDB;Uid=martin;Pwd=;"))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT priorita FROM nrp", cnn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "nrp");
            int pocetDGV = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            for(int i = 0; i < pocetDGV; i++)
            {
            List<string> LISTpriorita = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["nrp"].Rows)
            {

                LISTpriorita.Add(row["priorita"].ToString());
                string s = LISTpriorita[i];
                if (s == a1)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row1 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                    row1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                    row1.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                }
                else if (s == a2)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row2 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                    row2.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                    row2.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                }
                else if (s == a3)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row3 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                    row3.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                    row3.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                } 
            }
        }
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
    }
```

col1,col2,col3 are show in DGV

[image: my mysql example]

How can I load data from "priorita" compare with DGV and change text color in DGV rows? My code is not working. Have you any idea or solution? Thanks.

Comment: Can you upload screen shot of output with description so that we can understand your requirement

Comment: It is show no color (default black color).

Comment: @PiyushGupta I have table with 8 columns. In datagridview showing 3 columns. Once of not showing columns is column "priorita". For examle: datagridview show 3 columns (col1,col2,col3) ... if col4=a then font color=black or if col4=b then font color=blue , ...etc.

Comment: @PiyushGupta edit question with screen shot output. Thanks

Comment: Let me review, I'll tell tomorrow.

Comment: OK. Thank you for help

Comment: @PiyushGupta I have still same problem. Do you have some solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.SelectionForeColor = Color.Green;
```

fore color when u selected the cell.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

fore color for not selected state. This is the basic condition of coloring.

```
            int rowc = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= rowc; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString() == "a1")
            {
                for (int z = 0; z <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; z++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[z].Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                }
            }
            else if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString() == "a2")
            {
                for (int z = 0; z <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; z++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[z].Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                }
            }
            else if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString() == "a3")
            {
                for (int z = 0; z <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; z++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[z].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
```

I used index 7 for col8 because indexes starts with 0. I didnt tried but it must work. Dont forget, use this after filling DGV.

Comment: In this code you read from DGV but column where can be "a1,a2,a3" is not in DGV only in MySql.

Comment: I try select all columns from mysql to DGV, but still not work. It didn´t change colors

Comment: make an invisible column and give index of the invisible column to where writes "cells[7]"

Comment: Sorry It is my mystake. I had wrong set mysql. Your code is function. Thanks